# How to Scramble Image (Image Manipulation) in android?

Tags: android, image

I have been trying to achieve this on a image -

[image]

called as **Scrambled Image** on click of an item of a list.

The problem is that I am not able to achieve this and I am getting a non scrambled image as the old image.

Here is my code of Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final String CAMERA_PIC_DIR = "/DCIM/Camera/";
ImageView iv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    String ImageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + CAMERA_PIC_DIR;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ListFiles.class);
    i.putExtra("directory", ImageDir );
            startActivityForResult(i,0);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        String tmp = data.getExtras().getString("clickedFile");
        Bitmap ImageToChange= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmp);
        process_image(ImageToChange);
    }
}
void process_image(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 480, 320, false);
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    int x= width>>1;
    int y= height>>1;
    int[] pixels1 = new int[(width*height)];
    int[] pixels2 = new int[(width*height)];
    int[] pixels3 = new int[(width*height)];
    int[] pixels4 = new int[(width*height)];
    bm.getPixels(pixels1, 0, width, 0, 0, width>>1, height>>1);
    bm.getPixels(pixels2, 0, width, x, 0, width>>1, height>>1);
    bm.getPixels(pixels3, 0, width, 0, y, width>>1, height>>1);
    bm.getPixels(pixels4, 0, width, x, y, width>>1, height>>1);
    if(bm.isRecycled()) {
        bm.setPixels(pixels2, 0, width, 0, 0, width>>1, height>>1);
        bm.setPixels(pixels4, 0, width, x, 0, width>>1, height>>1);
        bm.setPixels(pixels1, 0, width, 0, y, width>>1, height>>1);
        bm.setPixels(pixels3, 0, width, x, y, width>>1, height>>1);
    }
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
}
```

Any positive answers will be appreciated.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Try removing `if(bm.isRecycled())` condition and everything should work fine

Comment: replace isRecycled() with what?

Comment: Replace it with `!bm.isRecycled()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `if(isRecycled())` by `if(isMutable())`

This should do the trick!

Comment: I solved my problem with the above solution but your solution should also work.